# UI in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

Hi i am going to develop blackbery application so i want to know the UI design fields(controls) which are available in blackbery can any one give me a good idea.

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: can i know which documentation you are telling?

Comment: Have you tried RIM developers website http://us.blackberry.com/developers/

Answer (score 3):

Google provided two good pages, amongst many others:

- [User Interface](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/UI-summary.html)
- [Blackberry JDE API – User Interface Field Reference](http://devsushi.com/2007/12/02/blackberry-jde-api-user-interface-field-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

This sample code might help you:

[How to add simple form fields in a Blackberry Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066146/how-to-add-simple-form-fields-to-a-blackberry-application/5066972#5066972)