# How to add simple form fields to a BlackBerry application?

Tags: java, forms, blackberry

Assuming I have a class inherited from MainScreen, how do I put up a couple of form fields for user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Inside the constructor

    LabelField label1 = new LabelField("Hello World Demo" , LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

    EditField firstNameEditField = new EditField(EditField.NO_NEWLINE | EditField.NON_SPELLCHECKABLE | EditField.NO_COMPLEX_INPUT);

    EditField lastNameEditField = new EditField(EditField.NO_NEWLINE | EditField.NON_SPELLCHECKABLE | EditField.NO_COMPLEX_INPUT);

    ButtonField submitButton = new ButtonField("Submit")
            {
                protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
                {
                    onSubmit();

                    return true;
                }
            };

        this.add(label1);
        this.add(firstNameEditField);
        this.add(lastNameEditField);
        this.add(submitButton);
```

Comment: and there are several field types to match your requirement like RadioButtonField, ButtonField, DateField etc. you can arrange these filed Horizontaly (using HorizontalFieldManager) or Vertically (using VerticalFieldManager).